# "No such file or directory" error when generating a report with Snakemake

Tags: shell, snakemake

I'm trying to generate a report automatically as described [here](http://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/reporting.html) using Snakemake's new feature. I get that the RST file should be created prior to workflow execution and located relatively to the Snakefile location (that is to say, not the workdir location).

Since my Snakefile is located in a subdirectory of the workdir, I defined the RST file like this:

```
report: "../../../../results/reports/peak-calling_workflow.rst"
```

Although the file does exist, I run into a "No such file or directory" issue:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/rioualen/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/snakemake/__init__.py", line 541, in snakemake
    report=report)
  File "/home/rioualen/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/snakemake/workflow.py", line 495, in execute
    auto_report(dag, report)
  File "/home/rioualen/miniconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/snakemake/report/__init__.py", line 374, in auto_report
    with open(dag.workflow.report_text) as f:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/home/rioualen/ChIP-seq_GSE20870/SnakeChunks/scripts/snakefiles/workflows/../../../../results/reports/peak-calling_workflow.rst'
```

Any idea how I should deal with this?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you confirm final resolved path should be `/home/rioualen/ChIP-seq_GSE20870/results/reports/peak-calling_workflow.rst`?

Comment: Yes it is, and the file does exist

Comment: If yoou create the .rst inside rules I suppose it works